# cakephp router change url and params

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I want to use router.php to change URL ( In CakePHP version 2.1.3):

Currently, I have URL like:

```
    http://domain.com/register/add?userName=123&fullName=abc
```

Now I want to change (rewrite) that URL to new :

```
    http://domain.com/regis-new?cus_name=123&cus_full_name=abc
```

My code in Controller:

```
 class RegisterController extends AppController{
    function index(){
       $userName = $this->request->query['userName'];
       $fullName = $this->request->query['fullName'];
    }

 }
```

How i can config router to apply new URL?

Thanks

Comment: "regis-new" to which action you do you want to call? I mean to you want to call "add" or any other action?

Answer (score 1):

```
Router::connect('/regis-new/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'register'
        'action' => 'add' // or new action name
    )
);
```

When you put start after alias means that pass any thing after alias.

The parameters doesn't have any thing to do with Routing.

:) Now check your input names in your view. e.g. if the input name was  "userName" rename it to "cus_name"

```
echo $this->Form->input('cus_name' array(
     'name' => 'cus_name'
));
```

Make sure when you get input values by their new names. e.g. in your action:

```
$this->request->data["cus_name"];
```

Comment: I tried with your guide code, it only run with url: 

http://domain.com/regis-new?userName=123&fullName=abc

But it can not apply with new parameters name. I tried with URL below:

http://domain.com/regis-new?cus_name=123&cus_full_name=abc

It is not run.